# Override a function' sub-function from a decorator?

Tags: python

Let's consider this piece of code where I would like to create `bar` dynamically with a decorator

```
def foo():
   def bar():
      print "I am bar from foo"
   print bar()

def baz():
   def bar():
      print "I am bar from baz"
   print bar()
```

I thought I could create bar from the outside with a decorator:

```
def bar2():
   print "I am super bar from foo"

setattr(foo, 'bar', bar2)
```

But the result is not what I was expecting (I would like to get `I am super bar from foo`:

```
>>> foo()
I am bar from foo
```

Is it possible to override a sub-function on an existing function with a decorator?

### The actual use case

I am writing a wrapper for a library and to avoid boilerplate code I would like to simplify my work.

Each library function has a prefix `lib_` and returns an error code. I would like to add the prefix to the current function and treat the error code. This could be as simple as this:

```
def call():
   fname = __libprefix__ + inspect.stack()[1][3]   
   return_code = getattr(__lib__, fname)(*args)
   if return_code < 0: raise LibError(fname, return_code)

def foo():
   call()
```

The problem is that call might act differently in certain cases. Some library functions do not return an error_code so it would be easier to write it like
this:

```
def foo():
   call(check_status=True)
```

Or much better in my opinion (this is the point where I started thinking about decorators):

```
@LibFunc(check_status=True)
def foo():
   call()
```

In this last example I should declare `call` inside `foo` as a sub-function created dynamically by the decorator itself.

The idea was to use something like this:

```
class LibFunc(object):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __call__(self, original_func):
        decorator_self = self
        def wrappee( *args, **kwargs):
            def call(*args):
                fname = __libprefix__ + original_func.__name__
                return_code = getattr(__lib__, fname)(*args)
                if return_code < 0: raise LibError(fname, return_code)
            print original_func
            print call

            # <<<< The part that does not work
            setattr(original_func, 'call', call) 
            # <<<<

            original_func(*args,**kwargs)
            
        return wrappee
```

Initially I was tempted to call the `call` inside the decorator itself to minimize the writing:

```
@LibFunc():
foo(): pass
```

Unfortunately, this is not an option since other things should sometime be done before and after the `call`:

```
@LibFunc():
foo(a,b): 
   value = c_float()
   call(a, pointer(value), b)
   return value.value
```

Another option that I thought about was to use `SWIG`, but again this is not an option because I will need to rebuild the existing library with the SWIG wrapping functions.

And last but not least, I may get inspiration from `SWIG` typemaps and declare my wrapper as this:

```
@LibFunc(check_exit = true, map = ('<a', '>c_float', '<c_int(b)')):
foo(a,b): pass
```

This looks like the best solution to me, but this is another topic and another question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you married to the idea of a decorator?  Because if your goal is bunch of module-level functions each of which wraps `somelib.lib_somefunctionname`, I don't see why you need one.

Those module-level names don't have to be *functions*, they just have to be callable.  They could be a bunch of class instances, as long as they have a `__call__` method.

I used two different subclasses to determine how to treat the return value:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import libtowrap  # Replace with the real library name.


class Wrapper(object):
    '''
    Parent class for all wrapped functions in libtowrap.
    '''

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__name__ = str(name)
        self.wrapped_name = 'lib_' + self.__name__
        self.wrapped_func = getattr(libtowrap, self.wrapped_name)
        self.__doc__ = self.wrapped_func.__doc__
        return


class CheckedWrapper(Wrapper):
    '''
    Wraps functions in libtowrap that return an error code that must
    be checked.  Negative return values indicate an error, and will
    raise a LibError.  Successful calls return None.
    '''

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        error_code = self.wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
        if error_code < 0:
            raise LibError(self.__name__, error_code)
        return


class UncheckedWrapper(Wrapper):
    '''
    Wraps functions in libtowrap that return a useful value, as
    opposed to an error code.
    '''

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)


strict = CheckedWrapper('strict')
negative_means_failure = CheckedWrapper('negative_means_failure')
whatever = UncheckedWrapper('whatever')
negative_is_ok = UncheckedWrapper('negative_is_ok')
```

Note that the wrapper "functions" are assigned while the module is being imported.  They are in the top-level module namespace, and *not* hidden by any `if __name__ == '__main__'` test.

They will behave like functions for most purposes, but there will be minor differences.  For example, I gave each instance a `__name__` that matches the name they're assigned to, not the `lib_`-prefixed name used in `libtowrap`... but I copied the original `__doc__`, which might refer to a prefixed name like `lib_some_other_function`.  Also, testing them with `isinstance` will probably surprise people.

For more about decorators, and for *many* more annoying little discrepancies like the ones I mentioned above, see Graham Dumpleton's half-hour lecture "**Advanced Methods for Creating Decorators**" ([PyCon US 2014](http://pyvideo.org/video/2617/advanced-methods-for-creat); [slides](https://speakerdeck.com/pycon2014/advanced-methods-for-creating-decorators-by-graham-dumpleton)).  He is the author of the **`wrapt`** module ([Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wrapt); [Git Hub](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/wrapt); [Read the Docs](http://wrapt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)), which corrects all(?) of the usual decorator inconsistencies.  It might solve your problem entirely (except for the old `lib_`-style names showing up in `__doc__`).